# load differents application context on spring boot apps

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im trying to load differents context on differents applications, let me explain:

I have 3 apps (DAOS - Helpers - Web) all of them are SpringBoot Apps but Web is WebApp (which has ServletInitializer)

The things is I tested each one with JUnit and their applicationContext its ok for each one, but when I deploy Web Project (.war) I got this error

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
    IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource 
    [/helper-context.xml]; nested exception is 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource 
    [/helper-context.xml]
```

I Already tried @Import(Class.class) but no good results.

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@ImportResource("/app-context.xml")
public class BaseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BaseApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@ImportResource("/helper-context.xml")
@Import(BaseApplication.class)
public class HelperApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelperApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@Import(HelperApplication.class)
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer, WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PortalProveedoresRegionalApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }



}
```

all contexts are in /src/main/resources and in JUnit as I said they are fine, my JUnits are ok.

So the question is, how can I load the contexts (Helper - DAO) on "main" application?

UPDATE 1

after add classpath:/context.xml i got this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to register bean definition with name 'documentoDaoHelper'
Offending resource: class path resource [helper-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'documentoDaoHelper' defined in class path resource [helper-context.xml]: Cannot register bean definition [Generic bean: class [com.sovos.helper.helpers.DocumentoDaoHelper]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [helper-context.xml]] for bean 'documentoDaoHelper': There is already [Generic bean: class [com.sovos.helper.helpers.DocumentoDaoHelper]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/home/asp4demos/portalregional/tomcat-8.5.28/webapps/PortalProveedores/WEB-INF/lib/helper-0.0.1.jar!/com/sovos/helper/helpers/DocumentoDaoHelper.class]] bound.
```

UPDATE 2

I added "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true" to my properties on Web project and its works, but I'd like to know why is overriding if defined context just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are packaged part of other JARs on the `classpath` then use the following

```
@ImportResource("classpath:/app-context.xml")
```

This would look for the resource within the JARs on the `classpath`.

Comment: Yes!! it was the solution, but I have another problem right now, can you check this out please ?. (I edited my question)